# TianoCore UEFI Development Kit build configuration, TargetTool produces unexpected configuration

Tags: firmware, uefi

I'm building **UEFI** application for **x86-64** based board. My application shall be based on **UDK2018** and utilizes its' build system. My build host is Ubuntu 17. I'm trying to use **TargetTool** to setup the build configuration for the emulation environment (that is, at this stage I'm like to build and to run my application on the emulator). I'm using the tool accordingly to the documented at the "EDK II BaseTools User Guides":

```
TargetTool --arch=X64 --platform=EmulatorPkg/EmulatorPkg.dsc --target=DEBUG --tagname=GCC5 Set
```

I'm expecting that after the above command finishes, the build environment will be configured. But this is not what actually happens:

```
TargetTool Print
```

generates the follow output:

> BUILD_RULE_CONF                = Disable
>
> TOOL_CHAIN_TAG                 = Disable
>
> TARGET                         = Disable
>
> TOOL_CHAIN_CONF                = Disable
>
> TARGET_ARCH                    = Disable
>
> MAX_CONCURRENT_THREAD_NUMBER   = Disable
>
> ACTIVE_PLATFORM                = EmulatorPkg/EmulatorPkg.dsc

What I'm doing wrong? What I miss in my understanding of how the tool is expected to work?

Comment: Just to mention, the generated configuration is not only unexpected, it is invalid.
If the `--multithreadnum` parameter is provided the generated configuration is still invalid, but now every key in the configuration file is assigned 'Enable' string.
It looks like there is bug in the tool implementation.

Comment: That looks like a very broken script to me (I can reproduce behaviour). I would suggest just editing the configuration file manually. And send a bug report on edk2-devel@lists.01.org.

Comment: Yes, the script is broken. I had fixed it in my local branch and going to submit the patch next week, hopefully.
Manual editing is not an option for me, I need the reproducible build automation. The whole framework feels me brittle and sensitive, I wonder if there are any real commercial projects that are built upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure there was an existing target.txt in the Conf directory of the workspace before running TargetTool? If you haven't run edksetup.sh in the workspace directory then target.txt doesn't exist.

https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/Common-instructions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There was an existing target.txt and I had run edksetup.sh.